# Make synclient settings permanent Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, settings

I wish to set

```
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient MaxTapTime=0
synclient CoastingSpeed=0
synclient VertEdgeScroll=1

syndaemon -d -t
```

I am using Lubuntu 18.04 HP-255-G1-Notepad

What is the easiest & safest way to make these settings permanent please?

Comment: One way to do it is to put those commands into a shellscript file and call that file from a desktop file, and put that desktop file into `autostart`. (I'm not sure if it is the easiest way.)

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do that. Where can I find out how to do this please?

Comment: I tested, and in Lubuntu it is even easier than in the other Ubuntu flavours. You need no desktop file for these commands, simply edit the `autostart` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lubuntu 18.04 LTS it is different from and easier than in the other Ubuntu flavours.

**Edit your commands into the `autostart` file**.

- Use your favourite editor, `leafpad` or `nano`, for example

  ```
  nano ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
  ```
- Save the file.

The next time you log in to the LXDE desktop environment of Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, your commands will be run automatically.

Comment: @Marty, You are welcome and good luck with Lubuntu :-)